# Having the same root ca for multiple organizations in Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In all of the fabric examples and documentation, usually there is a unique private certificate authority issuing certificates for each organization.
However, playing around with the code base, I do not see a limitation that different orgs need to each have different Root CAs.

Is there an issue with having the same Root CA for multiple organizations? Can the subject fields in the certificates be sufficient to use for identity verification in different fabric workflows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure that one organization does not masquerade as another, there must be something unique about the certificates that are issued by or for an organization.  Of course the easiest way to handle this is to have a separate root CA per organization.  It's also possible to have a common root but have different intermediate CAs for each organization.

But given your question is about basically using a single fabric-ca to issue certificates for multiple organizations, this is possible using the Organization Unit (OU) identifier feature introduced in v1.1 and later.  Basically, you can differentiate organizations using an OU in the issued certificates.  With Fabric CA v1.1 and later, you can create different affiliations for each organization and when certificates are issued, the OU will be set to the affiliation associated with the identity during the registration process.  You can either trust a single admin to properly register identities for multiple organizations, or you can create an hierarchical set of admins (meaning create multiple CA admins but assign each a different affiliation as admins can only register users under their own affiliation).

Then within your MSP definitions, you can using the config.yaml file to specify the OU with which to associate the MSP.  For example, if you look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/sampleconfig/msp/config.yaml, then

```
OrganizationalUnitIdentifiers:
  - Certificate: "cacerts/cacert.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "COP"
```

means that this org is identified by the root CA PLUS having OU=COP in the certificates.  This would also mean that the affiliation within fabric-ca would be "COP" as well

Comment: Thanks Gari, this is extremely helpful and was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hey @gari-singh, follow up question, can we have multiple values under the OrganizationUnitIdentifers field?

e.g. 
---
OrganizationalUnitIdentifiers:
  - Certificate: "cacerts/cacert1.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "COP1"
  - Certificate: "cacerts/cacert2.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "COP2"
 - Certificate: "cacerts/cacert1.pem"
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: "COP3"
---
Sorry for the atrocious formatting

Comment: You can do that if you need a single organization to be represented by multiple root cert / OU combinations.   If you are trying to represent multiple organizations, then you would have separate MSP folders for each organization each with a different config.yaml

Comment: Hi @gari-singh thanks again. I've been thinking a lot about the downsides of my  discussed approach (having essentially "one CA to rule them all..."). If each org has their own CA, then when an org, lets say "org3" leaves a channel, the channel can update its channel MSP to remove that org3's CA from its trust store. However, in the OU based approach, how does the channel enforce that org3's certs should now be rejected within the channel?

Comment: There would actually be a separate MSP entry for each org in the channel definition (yes - that means that there would be multiple copies of the root CA certificate for each entry) with each entry having it's own OU identifier.  So you would actually be removing Org3's MSP definition from the channel itself.  There is not actually a single MSP definition which contains all orgs but rather a MSP definition per org with each MSP differentiated by the OU identifier

Comment: I see a potential issue if admins have ability to create affiliations under this common root CA. e.g. If we have affiliations org1 and org2 and we have admin1 who can create identities and affiliations under org1 and admin2 who can create identities under org2. admin1 has OU=org1 in his cert and admin2 has OU=org2 in his cert. Now imagine they have the AffiliationMgr attr. admin1 creates a sub affiliation called org1.org2. Then admin1 registers a user, user1, under the affiliation org1.org2. user1's ecert will have OU=org1 OU=org2, which will make user1 valid in org2's trust store @gari-singh